# Reading the contents of a webpage with Python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to get the contents of a webpage. For some reason whenever I try `urlopen` it says there is "no such resource". I also can't use urllib2.

I would simply like to get the contents of a webpage such as http://www.example.com

```
import urllib
import re

textfile = open('depth_1.txt','w')
print("Enter the URL you wish to crawl..")
print('Usage  - "http://phocks.org/stumble/creepy/" <-- With the double quotes')
myurl = input("@> ")
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
    print(i) 
    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
            print(ee)
            textfile.write(ee+'\n')
textfile.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/austinhitt/Desktop/clases_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''',
urllib.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: You're using Python 3, yet the resource you're learning Python from is obsolete and uses Python 2. `urllib2` is no more in Python 3, its functionality exists mostly in `urllib` and its submodules

Comment: For a learning resource I'd recommend [Automate the boring stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) which includes a chapter on web scraping using Python 3.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree with you. I therefore need to know how to open a url in python 3. My IDLE shell says urlopen from url lib doesn't work.

Comment: When all else fails, read the docs [urllib.reqeust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

Comment: It helps to be more specific in your descriptions. You shell doesn't say _"urlopen from url lib doesn't work"_. It likely says _"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'"_ Since you are addressing people who use python often, the second one actually makes more sense to us.

Comment: You should post the complete error with backtrace.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I added the error.

Comment: change `urllib.urlopen()` to `urllib.request.urlopen()`

Answer (score 0):

For only the content use requests and if you want to play arround with the content you need to use scrapy, example:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://scrapy.org')
r.content
r.headers
r.status_code
```

Comment: I am not sure why you state scrapy is required in your example code.

Comment: No, I say that if he only want the content he can use requests but if he needs something else he can use scrapy, my example is using requests.

Comment: I think this would have been clearer if you stopped your first sentence at "requests", then give the code sample, then continue with "If you want to play..." _after_ the code sample.